# Troubleshooting KMS key policies for cross-account decryption

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have two Accounts a master account and a sub account that is used for logging. My goal is to send the CloudTrail logs from the master account to the s3 bucket in the logging account. At this point I have configured the the CloudTrail logs to point to the s3 bucket in the logging account. The issue is that they are not KMS encrypted. The KMS key policy in the logging account has been modified with the following statement

```
{
            "Sid": "EnableCloudTrailLogDecryptPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:ReEncryptFrom",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "organization_id"
                }
            }
        }
```

I've created a customer managed key based on the advice from [this documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8HSc.png).

Expected: Once I create this key in the logging account I should be able to add it to the CloudTrail in this section of the CloudTrail configuration.

[image]

However, I get the error `You don't have adequate permissions in S3 to perform this operation.` The specified AWS KMS key was not found in the same region as the target S3 bucket.`

Answer (score 2):

hope some of this tips helps, that's how i got it working

- created the customer-managed KMS on the same account + region as the s3.
- to the KMS, added following policy

```
   {
     "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Principal": {
         "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "kms:*",     # "kms:ReEncryptFrom", "kms:Decrypt" should be enough though
      "Resource": "KMS_KEY_ARN"
    }
```

- enable defatul-encryption on the S3 bucket, selecting created KMS
- in the cloudtrail (org managed account), provide the KMS with the full KMS_KEY_ARN, not just the name